# Javascript function is not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, css, browser

i am working on javascript onclick event, when i call function on button click it not gets works on IE browsers (IE-9 & IE-8)

code as following

```
<input type='image' src="mybutton.jpeg" name="submit" id="button" onclick="return myfunction();" />
```

i have defined function at top of my page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction()
{
  alert("This is testing");
}
</script>
```

Working on all other browsers like chrome & firefox but not in IE.

Please help me on this.

Comment: why are you returning the function ?

Comment: enable javascript in IE

Comment: Is it possible you mean 'onsubmit' instead of an 'onclick' ?

Comment: I need to do form validation in this function so i have used return in function

Answer (score 1):

Change your onclick from:

```
onclick="return myfunction();"
```

to

```
onsubmit="return myfunction();"
```

Comment: I need to do form validation in this function so i have used return in function

Comment: @MarkMartin I left the return in but changed it to onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like putting "listener" attributes. This works for me:

HTML:

```
<input type='image' src="" name="submit" id="button" />
```

JS:

```
function myfunction() {
    alert("This is testing");
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() { 
    return myfunction() 
} , false);
```